# Web.config files are being being populated with an empty string during upgrade InstallShield

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I've ran into an issue while performing an upgrade to our installshield 2010 project. 
There are Web.config files that are defined at 'XML File Changes node'.
Inside each web.config file there are attributes to replace during install (urls for example), this values are coming from dialogs and text boxes etc...
This functionality is working perfect during fresh install, the issue arises when i try to upgrade which works well while the upgrade populates according to its format in the ism project the values which were well populated at the first installation.

Any known way to workaround this?
another question is what should i do when my upgrade only adds another url to web.config?!

example: 'http://PAVEL-PC/Site/....'
ended up with: 'http:///Site/....'

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have configured an XML replacement value that looks something like this:

```
http://[SERVERNAME]/Site/....
```

The issue during maintenance is that you are only initializing the `SERVERNAME` property during first-time installs. Thus during non-first-time installs, the resulting value is `http:///Site/....`. To fix this, ensure that `SERVERNAME` is always initialized to the correct value. This may require storing a copy of that value somewhere (such as the registry, or an easily queried configuration file) that can be loaded via System Search.